# ST_Split with ST_Dump returns multipart Linestring with additional Splits

Tags: postgis, st-split

I am trying to split a lingstring using another linestring as my blade. The line to be cut crosses over itself at different locations. (to_be_cut is linestring, not multilinestring)

My query succesfully splits the line at the location of the blade BUT the other sections which cross-over themselves also get split into individual geometry_dump "paths".

Meaning i have 1 linestring that i wish to become two lingstrings - cut at the location of the blade layer.
But instead, my 1 linestring turns into 64 linestring segments which includes a split at the location of the blade (the line does not cross over itself at the location of the blade, so this confirms the blade is working)

```
SELECT
    ((ST_Dump(ST_Split(r.geometry,b.geom))).geom),
    r.line_identifier
INTO
    single_ling_test
FROM
    line_to_be_cut r,
    blade b
WHERE
    r.line_identifier= '555'
    AND b.name = 'blade_identifier'
```

Should i post the full geoms in WKT here ?

The line to be cut is quite long and i think the main cause of the unwanted behaviour is that the line crosses over itself.

I am looking for a way to avoid the additional splits at unwated locations - OR - for a method of reconstructing the decomposed parts while maintaining the split at the blade.

Comment: You could use linear referencing functions to achieve this.  Find the linear reference for the blade along the line then use st_linesubstring twice to return the line from 0 to the blade and from the blade to the end of the line.  https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Linear_Referencing

Comment: thank you @jbalk, after posting the question i actually started thinking/woking in that direction. Initially i needed the new segments for length measurements, so now i am just using ST_Line_Locate_Point to find the percentage of length along the line to be cut and calculating my values from there. Its actually a much simpler approach than i was previously attempting. Thanks for the suggestion!